# Return nxn array of Data from Handsontable using .getSourceData

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

I am attempting to get the source data object from a "handsontable" using [.getSourceData](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.21.0/Core.html#getSourceData) method. The console logs an array of arrays if I call the method using no optional parameters however when I attempt to pass these parameters I get console errors. I have a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05Lo5c6y/1/) that works to output array but does not work if I uncomment the optional parameter method.

```
var data = [
  [0, 0, 0],
  [10, 0.1, 150],
  [20, 0.2, 151]
]

var container1 = document.getElementById('Table'),
  hot1;

var hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, {
  data: data,
  colHeaders: ['Measured Depth', "Inclination", "Azimuth"],
  rowHeaders: true,
  minSpareRows: 0,
  contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row']
});

function countRows() {
  var ht = hot1
  var rowcount = ht.countRows() - ht.countEmptyRows();
  return rowcount;
}

console.log(countRows())

function submitForm() {
  var htContents = hot1.getSourceData() //getSourceData(1,1,countRows(),3)
  console.log(htContents);
}

$("#get_data").click(submitForm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got that function to work however what did work is to use countRows() to limit my output from returning blanks ie

```
for (i = 0; i < countRows(); i++) {
  md.push(htContents[i][0]);
  inc.push(htContents[i][1]);
  azi.push(htContents[i][2]);
}
```